# Clone a block device using 'cat'

Tags: embedded, busybox, buildroot

I am able to telnet into a router that's running a customized linux firmware. It was compiled using 'buildroot'.

I was able to dig out some specs of the router. I intend to clone the router's firmware for further study. 'dd' is not available so I tried using cat to throw the entire contents of the flash drive (mtdblock0) to my pc using netcat:

Router:

```
cat /dev/mtdblock0 | nc ip port
```

PC:

```
nc -lp port > routerFirmware
```

Then on my PC I used 'binwalk' to examine the downloaded file. The result is:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 4.0, compression:gzip, size: xxxxxxx bytes, xxx inodes, blocksize: xxxxxx bytes, created: xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx
```

Seems good so far. But '# unsquash routerFlash' results in:

```
Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on routerFlash
```

The most probable reason I think is that 'cat' and 'nc' are not able to clone the entire flash as I intend. I am stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the 'cloning' step was not the problem. My router vendor had used non-standard 'magic number' to create the squashfs system. I was advised to give [sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch) a shot. Fortunately, sasquatch correctly read and understood the file compression and other details, which unsquash didn't report correctly.

Result: I have a replica of my router firmware on my PC which I can study and analyze, just as I wanted. Looks good so far.